# NodeJS - config does not load configuration file

Tags: node.js, node-config

I am using the `config` module for `NodeJS`. The configuration files are copied in the output direction properly. However, the `config` module still does not load them.

```
import config from 'config';

// Prints "undefined"
console.log(config);
```

The configuration files are in the config sub-directory:

```
+ config
  > default.json
  > development.json
```

Answer (score 0):

In your example, you are only 'requiring' the config package.  You haven't actually asked for it to be loaded.

Typical use of the loading of config is based on the NODE_ENV value.  This describes the environment you are running the node app under.  E.g. production, development etc.

You can set the NODE_ENV value from the command line.  E.g.

```
export NODE_ENV=development; node ./src/app.js
```

Then, in your code, you then assign an element from your config file into a var or constant.  E.g.

```
const dbconfig = config.get('dbConfig');
```

So, using the below file as an example...

In /config/development.json

```
{
  "dbConfig": {
      "user": "some-user",
      "password": "somePassword",
      "connectString": "server:port/schema"
}
```

In the file you're trying to reading the config into...

```
import config from 'config';

const dbconfig = config.get('dbConfig');
console.log ("User is " + dbConfig.user); // should print 'User is some-user'
```

Don't forget to set the NODE_ENV value so that config knows what file to read from...

```
export NODE_ENV=development; node ./src/app.js
```

or, using your example

```
export NODE_ENV=default; node ./src/app.js
```